# Azure Databricks: Error, Specified heap memory (4096MB) is above the maximum executor memory (3157MB) allowed for node type Standard_F4

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I keep getting **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted** when I try to save my flattened json file in azure blob as csv. Some answers that I have found recomends to increase the executor memory. Which I have done here:
[image]

I get this error when I try to save the config:

[image]

What do I need to do to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

Adding part of the stacktrace that is causing **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted**. I have also tried with and without coalesce when saving my flattend dataframe:

```
ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 0d8c01f9-9ff3-4297-b677-401355dca6c4.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 79.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 79.0 (TID 236) (10.139.64.7 executor 15): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 15 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 52
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3235)
```

Comment: The error is basically saying that you can't set the executor memory size more than 3g so **you can change executor memory size from 4g to 3g** or you can upgrade your worker node type to `Standard_F8`.

Comment: but why you need to tune memory? Databricks selects optimal settings for you in the most cases

Comment: Im not sure but I'm using  `Standard_F4` if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experiencing similar error when executing the `spark.executor.memory 4g` command on my cluster with similar worker node.

[image: > Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).]

The cause of the error is mainly the limit of executor memory in specific cluster node is 3 Gb and you are passing the value as 4 Gb as error message suggests.

**Resolution:**

- Give `spark.executor.memory` less than 3Gb.
- Select the bigger worker type `Standard_F8`, `Standard_F16` etc.

Comment: do you know where you can find the default values per node?